# Why is the access control option not available for smart groups anymore? Fresh install

Tags: smartgroups, acl

civicrm 5.55.2
drupal 9.4.8

smart groups acl not available.
parent group has the option.

does not matter if smart group is parent or child[image]

Comment: as the 'target' group or the 'admin' group?

Answer (score 4):

Access control for the smart group was never supported AFAIK. Only for static groups

Comment: It has shown in the past, maybe a strange bug.. right now, I have smart groups showing the extra comma.. like , Mailing List,